# Do Same Action On All PDF Pages

Tags: windows, pdf

I want to do an action on all pages of a pdf file. for example I need to draw a rectangle, draw a simple line etc on all of pdf pages at once at the same location.

How is it possible?

Comment: PDF is designed for storage and display rather than document creation and editing.  You can do some limited editing, but that is often done in a separate "layer" and can sometimes not be handled correctly by other people's PDF viewers.  If you have access to the source document, you are better off editing that and then producing a new PDF.  You can also try converting the PDF to something like a Word document, editing the result, and then producing a new PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Would working with the header or footer of a PDF suffice.

If so try [AbleWord](http://www.ableword.net/) simple word processor and pdf editor.

It allows you to add table, text box, even image to header or footer of the page.